# Call Matlab in C++ code - using methods in engine.h

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, mex, matlab-engine

I write a C++ program whose only purpose is to call Matlab code. I have a main routine, which

1. read data in a file (matrices with high dimension 90000*24) into C++
   structures
2. pass these structures to Matlab code
3. launch the Matlab routine with these structures in argument
4. get the output data from Matlab and store them in C++ structures

In 2/, matrices are fields in a Matlab struct. The struct, say `MATLAB_STRUCT` has several matrix fields, `MATLAB_STRUCT.Z1`, `MATLAB_STRUCT.Z2`,... and some float fields `MATLAB_STRUCT.flt1`,...

What is the correct approach to set C++ matrices (`double**`) as the fields of the Matlab struct? So far, I came up with this, using `engine.h`

```
    mxArray* labcoeffs_array = convertVectorToMxArray(labcoeffs, 
                                                         coeff_nrows, coeff_ncols); 
    const std::string lab_coeff_name = "MATLAB_STRUCT.labCoef";
    engPutVariable(ep, lab_coeff_name.c_str(), labcoeffs_array);
```

where `convertVectorToMxArray` is an helper I wrote to convert `double**` to a `mxArray`,

```
inline mxArray *convertVectorToMxArray(double** mat, 
                                              const int nb_rows, const int nb_cols)
{
    mxArray *outputMxArray = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(
        (int) nb_rows,
        (int) nb_cols,
        mxREAL);

    double *data = (double*) mxGetData(outputMxArray);
    for (int r = 0; r < nb_rows; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < nb_cols; c++)
            data[r + c*nb_rows] = (double)mat[r][c];

    return outputMxArray;
};
```

But I have seen some other technique for assigning a value to a Matlab struct in the Cpp code (a float value though, not a matrix), imitating the command line syntax in a C++ string:

```
std::string setStruct = "MATLAB_STRUCT" + "." + "nB" + " = " + str->nB + ";";
matlabExecute(ep, setStruct);
```

with `ep` a pointer to a Matlab engine.

- Is it possible to adapt this approach with command line to assigning a value to a matrix type field of a Matlab struct?
- what is the best approach to assign a value to a matrix type field of a Matlab struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a matrix field in a struct, one option is to create a temp variable, and then to assign its value to a field of the struct:

```
// Create temp variable
mxArray* array = convertVectorToMxArray(mat, nb_rows, nb_cols);  
const std::string temp_name = array_name + "_temp";
int ret = engPutVariable(ep, temp_name.c_str(), array);

// Set variable to struct field
const std::string cmd = std::string(array_name + " = " + temp_name + "; ");
matlabExecute(ep, cmd);

// Delete array
mxDestroyArray(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a made-up example similar to what you described:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "engine.h"

// create mxArray matrix from an array of data
mxArray* data_to_mxarray(const double *data, int nrows, int ncols)
{
    mxArray *arr = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nrows, ncols, mxREAL);
    double *x = mxGetPr(arr);
    for (int c=0; c<ncols; c++) {
        for (int r=0; r<nrows; r++) {
            *x = data[r + c*nrows];
            x++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    // step 1: some data
    const char *fieldnames[2] = {"z1", "z2"};
    double z1[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0};
    double z2[] = {7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0};

    // open connection to MATLAB
    Engine *ep = engOpen("");

    // create structure with desired fields
    mxArray *st = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 1, 2, fieldnames);
    mxSetField(st, 0, "z1", data_to_mxarray(z1,2,3));
    mxSetField(st, 0, "z2", data_to_mxarray(z2,3,2));

    // step 2: pass struct to MATLAB workspace
    engPutVariable(ep, "st", st);

    // for the sake of this example, lets create a fake function
    engEvalString(ep, "my_function = @(x) magic(3);");

    // step 3: call some function with the struct as input
    engEvalString(ep, "out = my_function(st);");

    // step 4: retrieve function output
    mxArray *out = engGetVariable(ep, "out");

    // extract data out of it. This depends on the type of output.
    // Say the result was a numeric array
    double *x = mxGetPr(out);
    size_t len = mxGetNumberOfElements(out);
    std::vector<double> v;
    v.resize(len);
    v.assign(x, x+len);
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // cleanup
    mxDestroyArray(out);
    mxDestroyArray(st);
    engClose(ep);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already discovered `engPutVariable`, which is an efficient way to insert variables into the Engine workspace.  It can do this for mxArray of any type, not just a double matrix.

`mxCreateDoubleMatrix()` and `mxGetData()` are both functions in the "C/C++ Matrix Library API", which is documented here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cc-mx-matrix-library.html

Starting from those functions, you can find other functions for dealing with MATLAB struct variables directly from C++, including `mxCreateStructMatrix()` and `mxSetField()`.  A MATLAB struct variable is a "container" type, meaning each field is itself a MATLAB variable, so you'd set the appropriate field to the double mxArray you've already created.

If you really need to set a field of an existing struct, you can put the variable as a double array as you do currently.  Then, the `matlabExecute()` approach you mention is perfect.  It just takes the string that you want MATLAB to execute, which in this case is just "MATLAB_STRUCT.fieldname = existing_variable;"